# How to fetch individual properties of a mongoose Model?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, mongoose

I've just started playing with mongoose today after reading The Little MongoDB book. I'm quite new to this, so far I already know how to query my collections from mongoose and find documents based on their properties, but what I want to find out is actually how to display just one property of a document for each document in the collection, say, in an Express res.send(). Just as a learning experiment, if you will.

I've coded this snippet in CoffeeScript:

```
express = require 'express'
app = express()
http = require 'http'
server = http.createServer app
mongoose = require 'mongoose'

mongoose.connect 'localhost', 'linkreferrers'

# ## Ignore these configurations for now
# app.configure ->
#   app.set 'views', __dirname + '/views'
#   app.set 'view engine', 'jade'

linkSchema = new mongoose.Schema {
    referer: 'string'
}

Link = mongoose.model 'Link', linkSchema

app.get '/', (req, res) ->
    # Fetch the HTTP Referer from the visitor's browser, store it in the database, display a list of referers
    refererdata = req.get 'Referer'
    if refererdata?
        link = new Link {referer: refererdata}
        do link.save
    Link.find (err, links) ->
        console.log err if err
        res.send links

server.listen 5000
```

This sends the following data to the user's browser:

```
[
  {
    "referer": "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/",
    "_id": "50f0fdcb75d2543b38000001",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "referer": "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/",
    "_id": "50f18b0c95e3182a3a000001",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "referer": "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/",
    "_id": "50f18b58040ac5413a000001",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

How would I go about sending only the `referer` parameter of each document to the browser? I've tried replacing `links` with `links.referer`, but that sends `undefined`. Sometimes it throws an error saying that links has no 'referer' property. I've been stuck on this for a few hours now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to `find` lets you select which fields to include.  Try replacing that line with:

```
Link.find {}, '-_id referer', (err, links) ->
```

`_id` must be explicitly excluded with the `-` prefix, but the rest of the fields are opt-in.

Comment: Thanks so much. I read about that while learning about MongoDB but it must've slipped my mind when I was introduced to Mongoose. I was overwhelmed I guess, but thanks so much for clarifying in any case!

Comment: this answer seems to work, but is there a difference between this solution, and the following solution?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650258/mongoose-return-only-one-property-of-the-document-and-not-the-entire-document

Comment: @AlexMills No, just two different syntaxes for field selection. The field selection parameter uses the same format as the [`Query#select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) method.