# Mongoose return only one property of the document and not the entire document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean.io

Mongoose provides us lot of methods (`findOne`, `find`, `findByID`, etc.) to find document(s). All these methods return the **entire** document(s)/model.

Is it possible that when I search for a document, I just return **single** property from the document/model instead of returning entire document?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, by setting the projection object, which is usually specified right after the criteria object.

```
MyModel.find({criteria: 'some criteria'}, {'fieldToInclude': 1, '_id': 0})
                                          ^ Projection object
```

Note:
`_id` is always included by default, so only it's exclusion needs to be specified if needed.